# How can you get a list of unrecognized JSON fields in Gson like Jackson's @JsonAnySetter?

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, gson

So I currently use the Jackson parser and its libraries in my android projects. However, looking at the method counts for jackson and gson has me pondering about making a move to gson. After looking through different methods/syntax etc. I have been unable to find a gson equivalent to Jackson's @JsonAnySetter or @JsonAnyGetter.

Does this exist for gson? And if not, is there an work around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Gson basically has 2 commonly used annotations, `@Expose` and `@SerializedName`. To do what `@JsonAnySetter` and `@JsonAnyGetter` do, you'd have to write and register your own `TypeAdapter` that will group all fields that don't have a acorresponding `Field` and add them to a `Map`.

Jackson has so many more methods because it is a more complete API, with a larger feature set.